# How to change navigation bar of PHPickerViewController on iOS 15?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationbarappearance

I have an issue with navigation bar only on `iOS15`. I did all settings in `AppDelegate` but it does not help.

```swift
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.appMajorRed
       UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationController.self]).standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
       UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationController.self]).compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
       UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationController.self]).scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aByyO.jpg)